# Checkboxes dinâmicos

Tags: angular

Eu estou querendo criar checkboxes dinâmicos. Este código deveria me dar, no campo `categories`, um objeto com 3 itens `false`, mas não está dando certo. Onde é que eu estou errando?

```
export class FormPostsComponent implements OnInit {

    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private categoriesService: CategoriesService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [null],
            title: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
            body: [null, [Validators.required]],
            categories: this.buildCategories(),
            tags: [null],
            imgFeatured: [null],
            slug: [null]
        });
    }

    buildCategories() {

        const values = this.categoriesService.read().subscribe(
            categories => categories.map(
                x => new FormControl(false)
                )
            )
        return this.formBuilder.group(values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre pois o subscribe não efetua retorno das categorias, ele serve apenas para você pegar os dados da requisição e mante-la dentro do escopo, caso o valor não seja atribuído à uma variável. Você pode realizar a seguinte alteração para adicionar categorias à este conjunto.

```
export class FormPostsComponent implements OnInit {

    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private categoriesService: CategoriesService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [null],
            title: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
            body: [null, [Validators.required]],
            categories: this.formBuilder.group({}),
            tags: [null],
            imgFeatured: [null],
            slug: [null]
        });

        this.buildCategories();

    }

    buildCategories() {

        this.categoriesService.read().subscribe(
            categories => categories.map(
                category => this.form.get('categories').addControl(false)
            )
        );

    }
}
```